# How to select a dropdown list among the items with the same classnames and selcet from the dropped down hyperlinks0 <a>?

Tags: c#, selenium, web-crawler

I am a complete beginner to XML and any web-staff at all. I am dealing with Selenium 2.53 programming my webCrawler on C#. Need to choose the dropdown list among multiple ones with the same classnames.
I would be happy if this question could be answered in general for any problems of this sort.

[link](http://www.finam.ru/profile/akcii-usa-bats/3m-co/export/?market=25&em=18090&code=MMM&apply=0&df=9&mf=7&yf=2016&from=09.08.2016&dt=9&mt=7&yt=2016&to=09.08.2016&p=7&f=MMM_160809_160809&e=.txt&cn=MMM&dtf=1&tmf=1&MSOR=1&mstime=on&mstimever=1&sep=1&sep2=1&datf=1&at=1) to the page parsed

The upper two dropdown lists are stored in this tag

```html
<div style="top: 243.5px; left: 579.5px; width: 277px; visibility: visible; display: none;" class="finam-ui-dropdown-list">
```

But as there are multiple tags with the same classname (*"finam-ui-dropdown-list"*) I do not know how to find the element needed. I do not believe it is possible to deal with style attribute.

How do I select this option after? I have found that I can probably do that by visible text? which way is correct? Or I can click on it with a virtual mouse? how to choose an element within  tag in general?

```html
<li><a href="#" index="3" value="41">Курс рубля</a></li>
```

Unfortunately I am not really familiar with web concepts to pose better question but I hope I will be understood.

Comment: You said: "I am a complete beginner ..." So are you looking for us to teach you everything about XML, Selenium, web-"staff", and any other web concepts? Please have a read through [ask] first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find first element from class "finam-ui-dropdown-list" use following xpath:

```
//div[@class='finam-ui-dropdown-list'][1]
```

To select the option after that just find element with this xpath:

```
//a[.='Курс рубля']
```

and click on that. That element should be visible to perform Click() action so usually you want to do theses steps to select something:

1. Find drop down list and click on it to display values
2. Find element from drop down list using WebDriver Wait & ExpectedConditions and click on that element

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by))
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much. My code works perfectly, moreover now I have better understood XPath now having my own example solved.